# Magmi not importing images

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I use magmi for importing images from a remote url.
The images are downloaded and placed in media/catalog/products/*subfolders* but none of the products have images on either front or backend.

I have tried both the "image" and "media_gallery" fields with no results.

Magmi is placed in /var/www/domain/public_html/magmifolder

My settings are like this:
[image]

[image]

CSV example:

```
itemid;name;quantity;price;Weight;Images
45214;"Banana";351;2;1;http://domain.com/images/image1.jpg,http://domain.com/images/image2.jpg,http://domain.com/images/image3.jpg
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento StackExchange. Unfortunately, questions about 3rd party modules are offtopic here so I suggest you contact Magmi directly so they can help you with your problem as your question will most likely be closed

Comment: Hi, Sorry about that. I have just seen a lot of other Magmi questions with some great answers in here.

Comment: Yeah originally it was allowed so we kept the old Magmi questions here but they are offtopic now

Answer (score 1):

this will be lowercase **weight;image** and it **image** not **images**

```
itemid,name,quantity,price,weight,image,small_image,thumbnail
45214,"Banana",351,2,1,+/image1.jpg,+/image2.jpg,+/image3.jpg
```

Comment: I have column mapping to the correct fields, so I don't think that's the problem. Images is mapped to image, i also tried mapping Images to media_gallery with no luck

Comment: @DennisW i update the answer i have csv with this fromat and working for me.

Comment: but what about remote url? Would http://domain.com/images/image.jpg work? And how are your settings?

Comment: @DennisW i go with normal setting just look at this maybe helpful in your case http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13319/magmi-import-extra-images-how